# How to generate PDF labels with variable paper height

Tags: pdf

I'd like to generate PDFs for a label printer that has a roll of fixed width label paper (62mm) and a cutter that cuts after the end of the document. To avoid too much wasted label paper, I'd like to generate the PDF labels in a way that the text just fits the height of the label. Is there a PDF library that can do word-wrapping on custom paper width and can
a) extend the height of the paper to fit the text or
b) return the calculated height of the wrapped text?

Programming languages I consider are Java, Python, JavaScript, Ruby and PHP.